# Multiple barcode readers using SerialPort in .NET 4.0 with WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I have recently acquired 3 barcode readers (2 x Magellan 3300HSi and 1 x Gryphon 4400) both from Datalogic. The manufacturer provides an USB to COM driver which I've installed and allows me to use the SerialPort class to communicate with the scanner. Once I plug in the scanner (via USB) a COM port is added in Device Manager, allowing me to invoke the Open() method on it.

Part of the application I'm building is testing that the communication with the scanner is OK. This is done by performing a test scan. The methods used in this scan are:

**1. Opening the scanner**

```
public static SerialPort OpenPort(string comPortName)
{
    bool error;
    this.comport = new SerialPort();
    this.comport.BaudRate = 9600;
    this.comport.DataBits = 8;
    this.comport.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "One");
    this.comport.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");
    this.comport.PortName = comPortName;

    try{
        this.comport.Open();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { error = true; }
    catch (IOException) { error = true; }
    catch (ArgumentException) { error = true; }

    if (error)
    {
            return null;
    }

    return comport;
```

}

**2. The data handler listener**

```
    public void PortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort comport = sender as SerialPort;

        if (!comport.IsOpen) return;

        string data = comport.ReadExisting();

        MessageBox.Show("Data received " + data);
    }
```

**3. Attaching data handler**

```
    this.comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(PortDataReceived);
```

**4. Writing a Close / Detach method**

```
    public void CloseScanner()
    {
        if (this.comport.IsOpen)
        {
            this.comport.Close();
            this.comPort.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(PortDataReceived);
        }
```

For doing a test scan, I click a button, OpenPort is called, a SerialPort object is returned. I attach the data handler. I perform a scan. The scanned data gets displayed. I close the scanner.

**Here's the problem:**

This works like a charm if I only do it one time. If, after I close the serial port, I want to perform another test using the same port, the port is succesfully opened, but no data is received. The scanner (the device) issues an error beep the second time it's closed.

The strange thing is that this only happens with my Magellan scanners. The Gryphon works like a charm on subsequent reopen operations.

To make things even more strange, I've connected to the port using Putty's serial mode. When closing Putty and opening it again for a new session, the Magellan scanner is working just fine.

My guess is that this has to do with the way the serial port is closed in .NET. Maybe resources are not deallocated or something. Initially I thought this must be a scanner issue, requiring me to follow a certain protocol to close the connection. However, Putty seems to be working just fine with it. (I'm guessing Putty is using a different class for communicating with the scanner, maybe even WIN32 API).

If someone knows what might be the cause of this, please advise. Might this be some threading issues instead? I'm seriously thinking of looking in Putty's source code to see how they tackle this or using WIN32 API (this would overcomplicate things for me though).

**TLTR:**
Closing and reopening a SerialPort, makes it impossible for me to receive data from a barcode scanner. It only works the first time the port is opened. I'm using the manufacturer's USB to COM driver. What am I doing wrong? (code snippets above)

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have to work with those models and I do not know how affordable is the data communication.

Answer (score 1):

if you're developing barcode reader apps targeting a specific make of the device, it's probably better to use their sdk/objects instead of using the .Net generic SerialPort class. The .Net framework has NOT gotten better in that arena. It's still kind of slow and buggy.

You could look into Jan Axelson's site which contains a lot of examples in both .Net and Win32.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old but I figured others could use some help.  I am currently dealing with a Magellan 800i issue on 1 out of 60 computers and doing some research. Your code is a little vague and uses "this." inside a static function which will not compile. I am taking a guess that your recreating additional SerialPort objects and never releasing the original and your open function is not actually opening the port.  A bit more of your project would need to be posted.

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SerialPort comport = new SerialPort();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Buttonn on form that opens the assigned serial port
    /// Each barcode scanned will display a messagebox until you close the port.  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnOpenScanner_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.comport.IsOpen == false)
        {
            if (OpenPort("COM4"))
            {
                this.comport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(PortDataReceived);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This comport is already assigned.  Quit clicking the open button you silly user.");
        }            
    }        

    /// <summary>
    /// Button on Form that closes the serial port
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnCloseScanner_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseScanner();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the serial port
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comPortName"></param>
    public bool OpenPort(string comPortName)
    {
            this.comport = new SerialPort();
            this.comport.BaudRate = 9600;
            this.comport.DataBits = 8;
            this.comport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            this.comport.Parity = Parity.None;
            this.comport.PortName = comPortName;            

            try
            {
                this.comport.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }               
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Event Handler to receive scanned data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void PortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sendingport = (SerialPort)sender;

        if (!sendingport.IsOpen) return;

        string data = sendingport.ReadExisting();

        MessageBox.Show("Data received " + data);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the serial port.
    /// </summary>
    public void CloseScanner()
    {
        if (this.comport.IsOpen)
        {
            this.comport.Close();
            this.comport.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(PortDataReceived);                                
        }
    }       
}

}
```